# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast, in C when returning pointer

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, warnings

I'm coded function which splits 2 char arrays and integer into one string and returns pointer to new char array, but when compiling I'm getting this warning:

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> mapfile = world_to_char( "maps/", map, ".bin" );
>
> ^

Here is my code, first two are lines from file where gcc is giving warning to me:

```
char *mapfile;
mapfile = world_to_char( "maps/", map, ".bin" );
```

and function (I know that it works only with numbers from [0;99], but it's enough for me):

```
char *world_to_char( char dir[], int number, char ext[] ) {
    char id[ 3 ] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    if( number > 9 ) {
        id[ 1 ] = ( number % 10 ) + '0';
        number /= 10;
    }
    id[ 0 ] = number + '0';

    char *map;
    map = malloc( MAX_MAP_FILENAME * sizeof( char ) );

    strcpy( map, dir );
    strcat( map, id );
    strcat( map, ext );

    return map;
}
```

Why I'm getting this warning? I'm returning pointer not integer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: If you're using a C99 compiler, you should be getting warnings about calling a function that was not previously declared.  If you're not using a C99 or later compiler, or you're not getting the warnings, find the options that give you the warning.  If you're using GCC, consider using options as stringent as `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror`.  You can be more stringent if you like.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that `world_to_char()` is defined after `main()`, add a function prototype and it should work. So before `main()` add this

```
char *world_to_char(char *dir, int number, char *ext);
```

the parameters with "*java*" style `char dir[]` will become pointers anyway, so let's make it clear by changing them to `char *dir` instead.

The error message is because of *implicit declaration*, since the compiler haven't seen a declaration when you call the function it assumes that it returns `int`, so assigning `int` to `char *` is making a pointer from an integer without a cast.

Comment: A declaration would suffice: `char *world_to_char();` :-)

Comment: @Szeldon It's a common mistake, your question was really well written and formatted.